# Redirect users according to their countries

Tags: geotargeting

I have an international site. `www.example.com` is targeted to us www.example.com/in/ targeted to Indians, `www.example.com/bd/` to Bangladesh and so on. Users are redirected based on their IP addresses.

I would like to know whether the structure is right or not. Will it be better to redirect us visitors to `www.example.com/us/` instead of `www.example.com`?

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely up to you how you do it.

One reason I can see it being "better" to use `/us` is if some day you decide to add something else based on the country, you might find it easier.

If it were my site, I would likely make `example.com` be the same as `example.com/us` and be the fallback in case for some reason country is not detected.